# Stack build without storing output in nix store?

Tags: haskell-stack, nix

I've been running `stack build` on a project multiple times - and each time it seems to save the result in the `/nix/store` which requires a lot of storage over time.

Is there a way I can NOT save the result to the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't "not save the result to the store". (You can specify a *different* store, but that will make your problem worse -- you'll be storing an extra copy of your dependency chain in this store, and moreover, you'll be unable to download prebuilt binaries for parts of your dependency chain that are built by Nix's automated upstream build system, Hydra).

What you *should* do is garbage-collect your store, which will remove items that are no longer in use (as measured by reachability from an active "gc root" -- such as the `result` link created by the build process, programs which are actively running, or the set of software installed in a user's profile with `nix-env`).

This can be as simple as:

```sh
nix-store --gc
```

...or, if you have a specific item eating up space you want to remove:

```sh
# delete all instances of whatever, if-and-only-if they aren't reachable from a gc root
nix-store --delete /nix/store/*-whatever
```

Comment: For what reason is it not possible? Is it technically not feasible with the way nix works - or just something stack does not support?

Comment: The former. Keep in mind that one of the primary design goals of Nix is to have a build product be *fully reproducible*, derived only from variables in its derivation. The destination in the Nix store derived from the hash of those inputs is provided to a builder; if it was installed outside that location, it wouldn't be guaranteed to work (as build steps are allowed to hardcode fully-qualified paths to other parts of the same package, as in wrapper scripts).

Comment: I suppose if you knew a specific build *wasn't* self-referencing, you could tell Nix to build it (in the store), copy it out, and then use nix-store to delete the in-store copy... but that's defeating a lot of other Nix features (references to other derivations from that package will no longer be tracked, so you don't know that things your code *depends on* won't be garbage collected; any future attempts to build things that depend on it won't have access to a single well-known, canonical copy; etc).

Comment: (Also, if things aren't in the store, tools like `nix-diff`, `nix-copy-closure`, etc don't work)